# Faking a return address in Microsoft x64 Asm

Tags: assembly, stack, 64-bit

I'm trying to call a function via assembly (microsoft x64) with a fake return address. However, I seem to be unable to get the function to recognize the return address. As a test I wrote a small test app with a function that will print out all the return addresses it sees on the stack.

When calling this function with my asm I get either no return address printed, or a return address from some kernel function, or a crash.

Here is what I am trying:

```
sub rsp, 0x20           ; shadow space required by all functions
mov rax, 0xDEADDEADBEEF ; fake return address 
push rax                ; push the return address, simulating a call
jmp functiontocall      ; jmp to function
```

This crashes, not because it cant return to DEADDEADBEEF, but somewhere in the function. Evidently I'm somehow making the stack malformed.

I've also tried things along these lines:

```
sub rsp, 0x20
mov rax, 0xDEADDEADBEEF  
push rax                  ; push fake return address
sub rsp, 0x20             ; inner calling function starts here
mov rax, functiontocall
call rax
add rsp, 0x20             ; return address 1
pop rax                   ; should remove fake return address
add rsp, 0x20
ret
```

And interestingly this won't crash but when printing the calling addresses it just completely ignores my fake one. So, clearly I'm not setting up the fake return address correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope I've made clear what I'm trying to do but I fear I could have made it clearer.

As a sidenote, I am aware of this question [Faking ASM Return Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820377/faking-asm-return-address) and have tried the suggestions therein - but to no avail. Regardless, that question refers to x86 asm, not x64.

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably misaligning the stack. It needs to be 16 byte aligned before the return address gets pushed. Since in your first example you're allocating 32 bytes on the stack, something you did (or didn't do) before that must have misaligned the stack.

Comment: What kind of a function are you calling? If doesn't expect to have arguments in the stack?

Comment: @RossRidge Thanks. You were right - I'd miscalculated and I was misaligning the stack. Although, for some reason if I try to have more than one fake address it still doesn't see them. I will have to take another look and figure out why.

SamiKuhmonen Correct, this particular test function takes no arguments. Of course, when doing this for a real function that does expect arguments I will need to adjust things. For now it is more of a proof of concept.

Comment: If you want to fake the caller of the caller of the function you're going to need to a lot more work for debuggers or Windows' stack unwinder to see it. You need to follow the x64 calling convention completely, including creating unwind info for the fake functions making the call. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1eyas8tf.aspx If you just want it to actually return to that address, and you don't need to support SEH, you don't need to anything special other than having appropriate code at the fake return address for the caller of the function.

Comment: can't you just do something like "mov [ebp+4],0xDEADDEADBEEF" ?

Comment: EDIT: it has to be "mov dword ptr [ebp+4],0xDEADDEADBEEF" , or else it would be an  ambiguous call